# How to get a list of classes that extend from a base class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, oop, inheritance, reflection

consider following classes structure in Kotlin:

```kotlin
open class Base {
   ...
}

class A : Base() {
   ...
}

class B : Base() {
   ...
}

...

class Z : Base() {
   ...
}
```

How would I go around getting a list of ALL classes (`A`-`Z` in this particular example) that inherit from `Base` class?

I tried using reflection with `BaseTest::class.nestedClasses` and other reflection properties but they don't seem to be finding number of extending classes properly.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your `Base` class as `sealed class Base` and then access `Base::class.sealedSubclasses`

[Information about sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html)

Comment: Sadly, it still returns the count of sealedSubclasses as 0. I have also tried changing derived classes to sealed and the result is the same.

Comment: Did you forget to mark the class as `sealed`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 no, I did not. Even though the class is marked as sealed, `Base::class.sealedSubclasses` still returns nothing.

Comment: This is due to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46906